# which number corresponds to the right endpoint of line segment [0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I hold two basic opinion that

(1) Every line segment has two endpoints.

(2) The endpoint of a line segment is part of it.

So as for the line segment corresponding to [0,1],  if we remove its right endpoint,  which number corresponds to the right endpoint of the new line segment?  I don't think the number is still 1,  because we have already removed the point corresponding to 1,  thus created this new line segment, the point 1 is not part of the new line segment, so according to my opinion (2), I don't think the number is 1.

---

Update: A bounded continuous segment in a line is my definition of "line segment"

---

Update: I think I solved my question , see [answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3964059/34603)

Comment: What is your definition of "line segment"?  I would say that $[0,1)$ isn't a line segment at all.

Comment: As Eric Wofsey said, the set is not a line segment by any normal definition of a line segment

Comment: @EricWofsey a bounded continuous segment in a line is my definition of "line segment"

Comment: Well then what do you mean by "segment"?

Comment: The right end point is still $1$ and it is a half-open line segment. A line segment may not contain its end points -- it only needs to contain all points between them. Read [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20line%20segment,exactly%20one%20of%20the%20endpoints.)

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ has an infimum $0$ which happens to also be a minimum and also a supremum $1$ which also happens to be a maximum.  The half-open interval $[0,1)$ has an infimum $0$ which happens to also be a minimum and also a supremum $1$ which is *not* a maximum since it is not included in the half-open interval.  The half-open interval $[0,1)$ *does not have* a maximum.  "*(2) The end-point of a line segment is part of it*"  However you make your definitions you are using rigorous, this statement will likely be false.

Comment: For a *closed* (*real*) interval (*in the usual topology*), the infimum will indeed necessarily be included in the interval.  Similarly for the supremum and these will be the minimum and maximum of the closed interval respectively.  For any other type of  bounded interval however, the infimum/supremum does *not* need to be included in the interval.  They will still exist, but won't necessarily be included, and as a result the minimum/maximum need not exist as is shown by your example of $[0,1)$ not having a maximum.

Comment: Now.... you might be tempted to say that after removing $1$, there is still going to be some "largest" number *in* the interval... that it would be something like $0.999\dots$, however recall that $0.999\dots$ *is identically equal to $1$*.  With that in mind, any proposed maximum $m$ which is strictly less than $1$ we can show could not be the maximum since looking at the average, $\frac{m+1}{2}$, this will be strictly greater than $m$ and strictly less than $1$ and hence a number larger than $m$ in the interval contradicting that $m$ could have been the maximum in the first place..

Comment: This may involve [surreal numbers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/310797738_Some_Mathematical_and_Physical_Remarks_on_Surreal_Numbers) as the end point may be closer to $1$ than any possible real number.

Comment: The question is tagged with real-analysis, which implies that we deny the existence of such numbers.

Comment: You don't get to hold opinions about matters of fact.  If you consider $[0,1)$ to be a line segment, then (2) is simply false.  If you want to have a definition of "line segment" where (1) and (2) both hold, then you can only take CLOSED intervals to be line segments, but not open or half open intervals.  You need to look at what your definitions are, NOT what you would like them to be, before forming opinions about what they imply.  If you want a definition to imply something that it doesn't, then you either have to give up the definition or give up the implication.

Answer (score 6):

Your opinions (1) and (2) are inconsistent with your (implied) opinion (3), that $[0,1)$ is a line segment. If you truly believe all three of these statements, then it follows, as night follows day, that you believe that $2+2=7$, that the Moon is made of green cheese, and that you are the Pope. I would recommend that you carefully consider your three beliefs, and see which one(s) you are really committed to, and which one(s) you are willing to abandon, in the interests of not being in a state of self-contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Your second "basic opinion" is simply untrue. The number is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

First , it is helpful to  inform me to check whether [0,1) has a right endpoint after removing .

Second , just as [@ShubhamJohri](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964006/which-number-corresponds-to-the-right-endpoint-of-line-segment-0-1#comment8175604_3964006) informed that

> A line segment may not contain its end points -- it only needs to
> contain all points between them. Read [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20line%20segment,exactly%20one%20of%20the%20endpoints.)

so I misunderstood the definition of a line segment.

Answer (score 0):

There strictly speaking is no end*point* of a line_segment or ray at an open boundary. That said, the real number *corresponding to* an end of a line_segment defined by and terminating at a finite value {be it [included or excluded)} is simply that number, i.e. 1.